# django project cloned from github

Tags: python, django, github

Here am providing the error I am facing during run the project, firstly am cloned this project from `Github` and further add the `.env` file after that run the program and I get this error.

Please tell me the complete steps for cloning the project from Github and also the steps to run that project.

```
        /*****************************************************************************/
        Exception in thread django-main-thread:
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:\Users\its simi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
   packages\django\apps\config.py", line 245, in create
            app_module = import_module(app_name)
          File "C:\Users\its 
     simi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in 
     import_module
            return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'base'
        
        During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
        
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:\Users\its simi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 
     1009, in _bootstrap_inner
            self.run()
          File "C:\Users\its simi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 
       946, in run
            self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
          File "C:\Users\its simi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
      packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
            fn(*args, **kwargs)
          File "C:\Users\its simi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
         packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
            autoreload.raise_last_exception()
          File "C:\Users\its simi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
     packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
            raise _exception[1]
          File "C:\Users\its simi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
      packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 398, in execute
            autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
          File "C:\Users\its simi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
      packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
            fn(*args, **kwargs)
          File "C:\Users\its simi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
     packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
            apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
          File "C:\Users\its simi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
      packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
            app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
          File "C:\Users\its simi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
     packages\django\apps\config.py", line 247, in create
                raise ImproperlyConfigured(
        django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import 'base'. Check that 
     'vip_number.base.apps.BaseConfig.name' is correct.
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:\Users\its simi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
      packages\django\template\utils.py", line 69, in __getitem__
            return self._engines[alias]
        KeyError: 'django'
        
        During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
        
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:\Users\its simi\Desktop\vip_number\manage.py", line 20, in <module>
            main()
          File "C:\Users\its simi\Desktop\vip_number\manage.py", line 16, in main
            execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
          File "C:\Users\its simi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
       packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
            utility.execute()
          File "C:\Users\its simi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
       packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 440, in execute
            self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
          File "C:\Users\its simi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
       packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 414, in run_from_argv
            self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
          File "C:\Users\its simi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
       packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 74, in execute
            super().execute(*args, **options)
          File "C:\Users\its simi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
        packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 460, in execute
            output = self.handle(*args, **options)
          File "C:\Users\its simi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
        packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 111, in handle
            self.run(**options)
          File "C:\Users\its simi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
             packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 118, in run
            autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
          File "C:\Users\its simi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
          packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 680, in run_with_reloader
            start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
          File "C:\Users\its simi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
       packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 661, in start_django
            reloader.run(django_main_thread)
          File "C:\Users\its simi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
       packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 343, in run
            autoreload_started.send(sender=self)
          File "C:\Users\its simi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
        packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 176, in send
            return [
          File "C:\Users\its simi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
        packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 177, in <listcomp>
            (receiver, receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named))
          File "C:\Users\its simi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
       packages\django\template\autoreload.py", line 42, in watch_for_template_changes
            for directory in get_template_directories():
          File "C:\Users\its simi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
       packages\django\template\autoreload.py", line 15, in get_template_directories
            for backend in engines.all():
          File "C:\Users\its simi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
       packages\django\template\utils.py", line 94, in all
            return [self[alias] for alias in self]
          File "C:\Users\its simi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
      packages\django\template\utils.py", line 94, in <listcomp>
            return [self[alias] for alias in self]
          File "C:\Users\its simi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
       packages\django\template\utils.py", line 85, in __getitem__
            engine = engine_cls(params)
          File "C:\Users\its simi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
       packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 27, in __init__
            self.engine = Engine(self.dirs, self.app_dirs, **options)
          File "C:\Users\its simi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
       packages\django\template\engine.py", line 62, in __init__
            self.template_libraries = self.get_template_libraries(libraries)
          File "C:\Users\its simi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
        packages\django\template\engine.py", line 125, in get_template_libraries
            loaded[name] = import_library(path)
          File "C:\Users\its simi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
       packages\django\template\library.py", line 376, in import_library
            module = import_module(name)
          File "C:\Users\its 
     simi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", 
        line 126, in import_module
            return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
          File "C:\Users\its simi\Desktop\vip_number\templatetags\custom_tags.py", line 3, in 
     <module>
            from vip_number.users.models import User
          File "C:\Users\its simi\Desktop\vip_number\vip_number\users\models.py", line 3, in 
     <module>
            from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
          File "C:\Users\its simi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
    packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 5, in <module>
            from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
          File "C:\Users\its simi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
    packages\django\contrib\contenttypes\models.py", line 131, in <module>
            class ContentType(models.Model):
          File "C:\Users\its simi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
    packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 132, in __new__
            raise RuntimeError(
            RuntimeError: Model class django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType doesn't 
     declare an 
            explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

```
        INSTALLED_APPS = [
            # 'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
            'jet',
            'jet.dashboard',
            'django.contrib.admin',
            'django.contrib.auth',
            'django.contrib.contenttypes',
            'django.contrib.sessions',
            'django.contrib.messages',
            'django.contrib.staticfiles',
            'abc.users',
            'sellers',
            'vip_admin',
            'a.base',
            'abc.categories',
            'abc.category_tag',
            'abc.category_numbers',
            'abc.number',
            'abc.paytm',
            'abc.subscribers',
            'abc.homeimages',
            'abc.testimonial',
            'abc.faq',
            'tagconstants',
            'sekizai',
            'abc.wawebplus',
            'contact',
        ]
```

Comment: Please provide a quality description & format the error message and wrap it inside a single coded block. Can you also provide the GitHub link?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```bash
git clone https://github.com/xxx/django-project
cd django-project
python -m venv venv
source venv/*/activate
pip install django
python manage.py runserver
```

Comment: these steps seem complete. If there is a `requirements.txt` file, `pip install -r requirements.txt` can be done to install all deps.